# In HAML, syntax error, unexpected ')' not placed by me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, haml

I am rendering a drop down list of options in HAML with the following code:

```
  - @campaigns.each do |campaign|
    %tr{class: 'tr_' + cycle('odd', 'even'), id: "#{campaign.to_param}"}
      %td= link_to campaign.name, campaign
      %td= campaign.synopsis
      %td= campaign.focus_area
      %td= number_to_currency(campaign.goal_in_dollars)
      %td= campaign.approval_requested_at //line 34
      %td= link_to 'Approve', approve_admin_campaign_path(campaign)//line 35
      %td= form_tag({controller: "admin/campaign", action: "deny"}, method: "post") do //line 36
      = text_field_tag :reason, params[:reason] //line 37
      = submit_tag("Deny") //line 38
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
/Users/user/rails_projects/wdi/app/views/admin/campaigns/index.haml:34: syntax error, unexpected ')'
));}</td>\n      #{_hamlout.fo...
 ^
/Users/user/rails_projects/wdi/app/views/admin/campaigns/index.haml:36: unknown regexp options - tr
/Users/user/rails_projects/wdi/app/views/admin/campaigns/index.haml:36: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
));}\n    </tr>\n", -1, false);end;_hamlout.p...
                ^
/Users/user/rails_projects/wdi/app/views/admin/campaigns/index.haml:39: unknown regexp options - dv
/Users/user/rails_projects/wdi/app/views/admin/campaigns/index.haml:39: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...end;_hamlout.push_text("</div>\n", -1, false);::Haml::Util.h...
...                               ^
/Users/user/rails_projects/wdi/app/views/admin/campaigns/index.haml:39: unterminated string meets end of file
/Users/user/rails_projects/wdi/app/views/admin/campaigns/index.haml:39: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Where is this error coming from?  I'm not adding a parenthesis or new line character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form tag is not indented. Change it to

```
%td
  = form_tag({controller: "admin/campaign", action: "deny"}, method: "post") do //line 36
    = text_field_tag :reason, params[:reason] //line 37
    = submit_tag("Deny")
```